# How to overload operator+

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

So I want to overload `operator+`. Here is what I have so far, but it's still not working. How would I go in writing the syntax? 
Header file:

```
private:
        int month;
        int year;
        int day;

public:
    upDate();
    upDate(int M, int D, int Y);
    void setDate(int M, int D, int Y);
    int getMonth();
    int getDay();
    int getYear();
    int getDateCount();
    string getMonthName(); 
    friend upDate operator+(const upDate &lhs, const upDate &rhs);
```

My .cpp file

```
    upDate::upDate()
{
    month = 12;
    day = 12;
    year = 1999;
}
upDate::upDate(int M, int D, int Y)
{
    month = M;
    day = D;
    year = Y;
}//end constructor
void upDate::setDate(int M, int D, int Y)
{
    month = M;
    day = D;
    year = Y;
}//end setDate
int upDate::getMonth()
{
    return month;
}//end get Month
int upDate::getDay()
{
    return day;
}//end getDate
int upDate::getYear()
{
    return year;
}//end getYear

upDate operator+(const upDate &lhs, const upDate &rhs)

{
upDate temp;
temp.day = lhs.day + rhs.day; 
return (temp); 
}
```

In my main I have

```
upDate D1(10,10,2010);//CONSTRUCTOR
upDate D2(D1);//copy constructor
upDate D3 = D2 + 5;//add 5 days to D2
upDate D4 = 5 + D2;// add 5 days to D2
```

The error is that I can't add an object to an int. I've tried ways in which it worked, but it only worked for the D3 = D2 + 5 and not the D4. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's February 12 plus May 30?

Comment: @Kerrek: Assuming our dating system remains consistent for the next 13.8 billion years or so, approximately January 10th in the year 13797295634.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Uhm.. according to the implementation above it would be (using iso notation) 19991242 (the 42th day of December 1999), and there you have the ultimate question of life, the universe and everything: *what day of the month is Feb 12th + May 30?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need two functions:

```
upDate operator+(int days, const upDate &rhs)
{
   ... add days to date ... 
}
```

and

```
upDate operator+(const upDate &lhs, int days)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Which operator are you overloading on the second one?

Comment: The one to solve `d2 + 5` - or does the compiler figure out that `d2 + 5` and `5 + d2` is the same - I don't remember that working last time I tried, but I guess I could have misunderstood it. I admit I haven't been doing much with customer operators.

Comment: Ah, sorry, now I see what you mean - there was a + missing... ;)

Answer (score 1):

To minimize coding redundancy, here's how one would usually implement various related operations:

```
struct Date
{
    Date & operator+=(int n)
    {
        // heavy lifting logic to "add n days"
        return *this;
    }

    Date operator+(int n) const
    {
        Date d(*this);
        d += n;
        return d;
    }

    // ...
};

Date operator(int n, Date const & rhs)
{ 
    return rhs + n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
upDate operator+(const upDate &lhs, int days)
{
    ...
}

upDate operator+(int days, const upDate &rhs)
{
    ....
}
```

Alternatively you could have a constructor taking a single int and let the conversions work for you.... but this is a little weird as you're adding a duration whereas your class represents a date. But your actual operator+ has this problem anyway - what does it mean to add 2 dates?

EDIT: Take a look at chrono in c++11, it makes a good distinction between points *in* time and durations *of* time